# Read and Write from Host to Slave through Serial Port in vb.net, Unable to stop program, break loop, without quitting

Tags: vb.net, loops, user-interface, serial-port, shapes

I have written code to read and write to a serial port. I need it to indefinitely loop, I have  been unable to figure a way to place a button to stop the loop, it will stop if there are errors.

I have searched the internet and have tried people's suggestions, but yet to get one actually work for me.

I am also unsure if the display data is updating frequently enough. This is my first time to use shapes.

I am still new to all this.

```
'this code has no provision to stop voluntarily, apart from quitting the program.
Imports System.IO.Ports

Class form1
    '==CONTROL CHARACTERS- as per spec==
    '==start and stop values==
    Dim STX As Byte = &H2
    Dim ETX As Byte = &H3

    '==Read==
    Dim read As String = "R"

    '==Acknowledgment==
    Dim ACK As Byte = &H6

    '==class and address==
    Dim DeviceClass As String = "E"
    Dim DeviceAddress As String = "1"

    '==Host Commane==
    Dim hostCommand As String
    '==STX E 1 R REG1 REG0 ETX==

    '==Command to read==
    Dim readSlave As String
    '==STX E 1 ACK REG1 REG0 D1 D0 ETX==

    '==array of register values==
    Dim REG = New String() {"22", "23", "2F", "30"}

    '==set and open port==NB not using get portname- COM1 to be used as dedicated port as spec==
    Private Sub btnStartReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartReset.Click
        If SerialPort1.IsOpen = False Then
            '==Open and set COM1 as host==
            Try
                '==Set COM1 as portname==
                SerialPort1.PortName = "COM1"
                '==Port settings==
                SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
                SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None
                SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One
                SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
                SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 100
                '==Open port==
                SerialPort1.Open()
                rtbCom1.Text = "COM1 Ready"
                tmrPoll.Start()
            Catch ex As Exception
                rtbCom1.Text = "open error " & ex.Message
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrPoll_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrPoll.Tick
        '==timeout error counter==
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        '==Prevent unnecessary timeout errors/allow time lag for port to open==
        Do While SerialPort1.IsOpen = True
            '==Loop through Register==
            For Each register In REG
                '==STX E 1 R REG1 REG0 ETX==
                hostCommand = (STX & DeviceClass & DeviceAddress & read & register & ETX)
                Try
                    '==Loop Host Commands for Register==
                    SerialPort1.WriteLine(hostCommand)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    rtbCom1.Text = "Write Error: " & ex.Message
                End Try
                Try
                    '==readline to separate data==
                    readSlave = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
                    '==display data in GUI==
                    lst1.Items.Add(readSlave)
                    '==Get Register Value==
                    '==STX E 1 ACK REG1 REG0 D1 D0 ETX==
                    '==2-E-1-6-R-R-D-D-3==
                    '==Get the Data Value for Individual Register==
                    Dim reg = readSlave.Substring(4, 2)
                    '==convert data to integer, so data can be displayed graphically==
                    Dim D1 = CInt(readSlave.Substring(6, 1))
                    Dim D0 = CInt(readSlave.Substring(7, 1))
                    '==Display received substring values==
                    Select Case reg
                        Case Is = "22"
                            'list box until advised.
                            lst1.Items.Add(reg & D1 & D0)
                        Case Is = "23"
                            '==display data as shape==
                            '==0-100==
                            shpTemp.Width = (D1 + D0)
                        Case Is = "2F"
                            '==0-5==
                            shpAmp.Width = (D1 + D0) * 20
                        Case Is = "30"
                            '==0-40==
                            shpVolt.Width = (D1 + D0) * 2.5
                    End Select
                Catch ex As Exception
                    rtbCom1.Text = "Read error: " & ex.Message
                    i += 1
                End Try
                If i > 2 Then
                    rtbCom1.Text = "Operation Aborted: 3 timeout errors."
                    '==Stop program if 3 timeout errors- as spec/closed port==
                    SerialPort1.Close()
                    rtbCom1.Text = "port closed - Operation Aborted: 3 timeout errors."
                    shpAmp.Width = 1
                    shpTemp.Width = 1
                    shpVolt.Width = 1
                    tmrPoll.Stop()
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Next
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With WinForm projects, the UI is single-threaded.  The message loop (which processes incoming messages from the OS, such as button clicks) runs on the same thread as the UI event handlers, such as your `tmrPoll_Tick` event handler method.  Therefore, until your event handler from one UI event exits, the message loop will not process the next OS message.  Since that is the case, if you sit in an infinite loop in `tmrPoll_Tick`, it will completely lock up the UI because it will block the message loop from processing any more messages.

For that reason, as a rule, in WinForm projects, you should never create an infinite or long-running loop which runs in a UI event handler.  You need to either redesign your code so it is more event-driven (doing one piece of work at a time in a recurring event), or you need to run the loop in a separate thread so that it doesn't block the UI thread.  If you want to do it with a separate thread, a popular option is to use the `BackgroundWorker` component, which you will find in your form-designer tool box.